Visual Studio 2022 - Multiple Reports in a single Viewer/File
I'm trying to display multiple reports in a single Crystal Reports Viewer/File but I'm unsure how to do it.
So far I have this working for a single report in the Crystal Reports Viewer:-
    private void btnDisplayInViewer_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        String Application_Path = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);
        cryRpt = new ReportDocument();            
        cryRpt.Load(Application_Path + "\\Order_Report.rpt");
        (cryRpt.ReportDefinition.ReportObjects["tOrder_Ref_Display"] as TextObject).Text = "1";
        crystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = cryRpt;
        crystalReportViewer1.Refresh();
    }

So far I have this working for a single report to a file:-
    private void btnToPrinter_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        String Application_Path = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);
        cryRpt = new ReportDocument();
        cryRpt.Load(Application_Path + "\\Order_Report.rpt");
        (cryRpt.ReportDefinition.ReportObjects["tOrder_Ref_Display"] as TextObject).Text = "1";
        cryRpt.PrintToPrinter(1/*Copies*/, true/*collated*/, 0/*Start Page*/, 0/*End Page*/);
    }

Any examples of how to add multiple reports to either scenarios so I only have a single viewer/file?
tia
This is my workaround:-
I used PDFSharp.
I installed via Visual Studio|Tools|NuGet Package Manager|Manage NuGet Packages for Solution...

Make sure used in the project references:-

Add the usings:-
using PdfSharp;
using PdfSharp.Pdf.IO;
using PdfSharp.Pdf;
using PdfSharp.Drawing;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.IO;//File.Delete

And this is my example code:-
        private void btnExport_Multiple_PDFs_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        String Destination_File_Location_Name = "c:\\Temp\\";
        String PDF_File_Extension = ".pdf";
        String Report_Name = "Report.rpt";

        #region Nested method to add pages.
        void CopyPages(PdfDocument from, PdfDocument to)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < from.PageCount; i++)
            {
                to.AddPage(from.Pages[i]);
            }
        }
        #endregion Nested method to add pages.

        ExportOptions CrExportOptions;
        DiskFileDestinationOptions CrDiskFileDestinationOptions = new DiskFileDestinationOptions();
        PdfRtfWordFormatOptions CrFormatTypeOptions = new PdfRtfWordFormatOptions();
        String Application_Path = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);

        PdfDocument outPdf = new PdfDocument();

        #region Loop through a number of times to generate multiple reports.
        for (int m = 1; m < 4; m++)
        {
            CrDiskFileDestinationOptions.DiskFileName = Destination_File_Location_Name + m.ToString() + PDF_File_Extension;

            cryRpt = new ReportDocument();
            cryRpt.Load(Application_Path + "\\" + Report_Name);
            (cryRpt.ReportDefinition.ReportObjects["tOrder_Ref_Display"] as TextObject).Text = m.ToString();
            CrExportOptions = cryRpt.ExportOptions;
            {
                CrExportOptions.ExportDestinationType = ExportDestinationType.DiskFile;
                CrExportOptions.ExportFormatType = ExportFormatType.PortableDocFormat;
                CrExportOptions.DestinationOptions = CrDiskFileDestinationOptions;
                CrExportOptions.FormatOptions = CrFormatTypeOptions;
            }
            cryRpt.Export();

            PdfDocument one = PdfReader.Open(CrDiskFileDestinationOptions.DiskFileName, PdfDocumentOpenMode.Import);
            CopyPages(one, outPdf);
            // Remove the Crystal Report File thats been exported
            File.Delete(CrDiskFileDestinationOptions.DiskFileName);
        }
        #endregion Loop through a number of times to generate multiple reports.

        #region Check Temp Directory Exists. If not the create. 
        if (!Directory.Exists(Destination_File_Location_Name))
        {
            Directory.CreateDirectory(Destination_File_Location_Name);
        }
        #endregion Check Temp Directory Exists. If not the create.            

        // Save the Output PDF to file
        outPdf.Save(Destination_File_Location_Name + PDF_File_Extension);
        // Preview the PDF
        Process.Start(Destination_File_Location_Name + PDF_File_Extension);
    }

It will add each Crystal Report Page into a single PDF document.

For this the subreport comes in picture.
